# Checking request parameter in spring FTL

Tags: spring

I'm building a page with Spring trying to use FTL.
I'm trying to add a check to see if I have the request parameter 'success' in the url to tell the user that the registration worked when redirecting to the login page. But I'm not able to make it work. Only the 'error' parameter works.

```
<#if RequestParameters['error']??>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    There was a problem logging in. Please try again.
</div>
<#elseif RequestParameters['success']??>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    Success
</div>
</#if>
```

Any ideas?